# Problem with creating a form meant to insert info into different tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm pretty much a Rails beginner, at the moment developing a rather complex webapp in Rails **2.2**.

So, in this webapp, there are "factories". Not the design pattern, mind you, actual factories (it's a game).

For each factory in a player's team, there are a bunch of options he can take.

- Level of maintenance for the machinery
- Rewards for workers
- etc.

I have two problems with this:

1. These are all checkboxes, and the checkbox needs to be defaulted with the answer already stored in the db. What I mean is the check must be already in the box if the player already checked it (sorry if this passage is confusing).
2. This information is stored in multiple tables. The level of maintenance in a factory is saved in one table, while the performance bonus given to workers is in another one.

Can anyone help me with this? This is all way over my head.

Thanks all.

Comment: How are the options currently stored (checkboxes) - as booleans in a table? What are the involved models and their relationships?

Comment: Show us some more code: how do your models look (especially the relations between the models involved), and your view-code. I guess you are having troubles with getting the stuff saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand question 1, keep it simple and pretend the attributes you want to access are in the factories table.  The design pattern then is pretty simple:

Database schema:

```
create_table :factories do |t|
  t.boolean :now_operating, :default => true, :null => false
  ...
```

Controller:

```
def edit
  @factory = Factory.find(params[:id])
  if request.post?
    @factory.update_attributes(params[:factory])
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% form_for :factory, @factory, :url => { :action => "edit" }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.checkbox :now_operating %>
  ...
```

You can do this with less code, in fact with none at all if you use RESTful resources and follow naming conventions, but this is a little too much magic to start off, because it conceals what rails is doing for you.

Namely: when the :get action loads an object matching the object name passed to form_for, rails will populate the form fields with that object's attribute values from the database.  Then, when the client submits the form, rails encodes those fields into the request as params for that object, which you can then update in the :post action.  See the official [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for a more detailed treatment.

I apologize if that was a little too basic, but it's important to get the basic pattern because the general approach to solving problem 2 is the same:

1. Load the objects in your :get action.
2. Render a form with the objects enclosed.
3. Save the params for each object.

There are several ways of actually doing this for forms with multiple objects.  I suggest you see the various tutorials listed under Item 8, Building Complex Forms, in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Two last points to consider:

- Do you really need those extra tables?  If each maintenance row
  contains attributes for a single
  factory, it may make more sense to
  just put the attributes in the
  factory table and simplify your forms
  and actions.
- Attributes such as :maintenance_level might be more
  appropriately represented as a
  :string type with a radio_button in
  the form to set the level.

Answer (score 1):

if the child entities (level of maintenance, performace, etc) are linked to the Factory, then you can use nested model forms.

You can check some info about nested forms [here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms), or just google "rails nested forms" and you'll get plenty of blog posts and tutorials.

--EDIT 
Seeing that you added that you're using rails 2.2, you could try to use [simple_forms](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) or [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) to create the nested forms (this is just a suggestion as I have no idea if it works). And I can only thing of setting the values manually to update the models.